# SQL Server 2008 suddenly stopped connecting

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-connection

This one is strange...

I have a server at home that's part of my home network (workgroup). It has SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 running on it. I've been connecting to it from my (other) desktop regularly for months now and tonight all of a sudden I can't connect to it from my desktop. I *can* connect to it if I RDP onto the server and connect locally. I've checked the event logs on the server and nothing interesting appears.

Here's the (unhelpful) error returned by Management Studio from my desktop when trying to connect to the server:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
>   the operation or the server is not responding. (.Net SqlClient Data
>   Provider)

I'm kinda stumped by this really. I've tried connecting with sqlcmd - it tells me this:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : Unable to
>   complete login process due to delay in opening server connection.

Not really sure what that means. I've made sure SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections and have used netstat -a and seen that it's listening on port 1433 (for all IPs).

Anyone got any helpful ideas? I've rebooted the server too, but that didn't change anything.

EDIT/UPDATE: from my desktop I can ping the server by host name and I get something like this:

> Reply from fe80::9077:4449:4b37:cad1%12: time<1ms

but if I try to ping it by it's IP address it times out. I wonder if that points to some kind of IPv4 vs. IPv6 issue?

Comment: Did you try restarting thr server or services? :)

Comment: Yeah, I tried all of the obvious stuff, restarting the services, restarting the server (OS) itself, nothing has helped so far.

Comment: maybe better suited for http://superuser.com ?

Comment: is the IP adress resolved from your desktop the actual ipadress of the server ? Run a `ipconfig /all` from the server, and do a `nslookup` from your desktop to see if IP addresses are matching. I had cases when the DNS was messed up, and IP address resolution wrong.

Comment: Steve - thanks for the nslookup tip. I did that and the error I got made me realize I was connected to my work's VPN and it was using that DNS to try to find my server here on my home workgroup and so it was failing. :( I feel like a dummy now. If you want to post your comment as an answer I'd be glad to accept. Thanks.

Comment: @SteveB Want to add the answer?

Comment: @benni_mac_b - the issue was that I was connected to my works' VPN from home which meant host name to IP resolutions were going against my work's DNS, and it couldn't find my home machine name on their network (because it was my home machine, not a machine on their network). Once I disconnected from the VPN connection (Cisco client) - I was again able to connect to SQL Server just fine (because Windows was no longer using my work's DNS to find it). Hope that makes sense. Basically nslookup made me realize that I was pointing at the wrong DNS server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the IP adress resolved from your desktop the actual ipadress of the server ?

Run a `ipconfig /all` from the server, and do a `nslookup` from your desktop to see if IP addresses are matching. I had cases when the DNS was messed up, and IP address resolution was wrong.